# Destroyed fragment content remains on screen

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-background, android-thread

I have fragments making API call via `Retrofit` + `RxJava`. I subscribe the `Subscription` in `onActivityCreated` and dispose at `onDestroy`. When I switch from `FragmentA` to `FragmentB` while `FragmentA` is still processing the API call, `FragmentB` appears below the content of `FragmentA`. It means `FragmentA` contents remains on top of the screen and there is no control over it.

**FragmentA.java**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.swipe_refresh) SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefresh;
    @BindView(R.id.recycler_view) RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private ItemsAdapter mAdapter;

    private CompositeDisposable mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        mSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                fetchItems();
            }
        });

        mAdapter = new ItemsAdapter();

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(true);
        fetchItems();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mCompositeDisposable.clear();
    }

    private void fetchItems() {
        RequestInterface requestInterface = Utils.createService();
        mCompositeDisposable.add(requestInterface.getItemsForA()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Response>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull Response response) throws Exception {
                    mAdapter.swapItems(response.getItems());
                    mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error: " + throwable.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }));
    }
}
```

**FragmentB.java**

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    //Same as `FragmentA` but different API call
}
```

I have also did some logging and found out that all of the life-cycle methods for `FragmentA` including `onDestroyView` gets called.

Comment: can you share your Activity code, where written code for fragment transection?

Comment: Actually, it is not fragment transaction. It is `ViewPager` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Also there is no problem when switching the fragments after the API call is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call following methods on `SwipeRefreshLayout` to fix this.

```
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    swipeRefreshLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
    swipeRefreshLayout.clearAnimation();
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed it! I knew it had to do something with the `SwipeRefreshLayout`. Thanks anyway.